# Parameters merged to request in service provider are lost outside service provider - Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation, service-provider

I have encountered unusual behaviour in my service provider in Laravel 5.6

I have a custom validation rule which used to live in my Form Request. It worked just fine in the form request, however I decided to move it and some other rules to a custom Service Provider and have since run into a strange issue.

```
Validator::extend(
      'spatial_reference',
      function ($attribute, $value, $params, $validator) {
          $spatialReferences = calculateSpatialReferences($value);
          if (!empty($spatialReferences['latitude'])) {
              request()->merge($spatialReferences);
              Log::info(request()->all());/*The fields are merged here*/
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      },
  'The :attribute is not in a valid format.'
  );
```

When the above is run from the form request, all is fine and the latitude, longitude and grid reference are then available from the request once the form request has validated successfully.

However if I move the code to the boot method of a Custom Service Provider the request merge works and I can verify that the array is merged to the request by logging it, but the new fields are non-existent and not accessible outside of the service provider.

I presume this has something to do with the life cycle but I cannot find the why of it even after significant research on-line.

I'd appreciate a pointer in the right direction.